# embedding google sheet in a html page - refuse to execute inline script

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to embed google sheet in a simple HTML page.
I am following the instruction from:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

I get the following in the console

`Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ktarjbJmNtF8IylbwgjSQoKrcQSdXJkqf60bj4nusHA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback`

In the browser I get the following
`Cannot GET /undefined`

I am embedding the google sheet provided URL in a div like the following

```
<div class="text-center section-heading" style="margin-top: 80px;">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTuYr0tEiCqzkPHDgAEMxbUFfYAGI-XADsjCCC05dHuSU-5foLqR9CTHjjq-Xgh-O6SnM4ukIuKMywK/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you embedding the HTML provided? The error code points at an issue with the way you have the resource, you may want to check [this](https://csper.io/blog/csp-violates-the-content-security-policy-directive)

Comment: I modifed the post to show how I embedded

Comment: I add the following to the head <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://docs.google.com/">.  Now the sheet is displayed, but the console errors are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding the `HTML` obtained from sheets as part of your web site is being added as an inline resource, you could [migrate](https://csper.io/docs/guide-removing-inline) the inline resource to a JavaScript/style file instead.

This is due to **Content-Security-Policy blocks all inline resources.**

Comment: can you share an example.